# Can't convert datetime with am/pm from character to integer

Tags: r, strptime

After uploading datetime data from a csv file, I can see the datetime with am/pm but it is in a character format and thus cannot add a regression line.
When trying to convert to an integer using stprtime I create a new column that is now an integer, however it has lost the am/pm information. How can I retain this information?

Sample data "wpplot":

```
    Date    Irrigation  Rep ID  WP
6/29/17 12:40 PM    Reduced 1   11B -14.3
6/29/17 12:50 PM    Reduced 1   11B -14.4
6/29/17 1:00 AM Reduced 1   11B -14.5
6/29/17 1:10 AM Reduced 1   11B -14.5
6/29/17 1:20 AM Reduced 1   11B -14.5
6/29/17 1:30 AM Reduced 1   11B -14.5
6/29/17 1:40 AM Reduced 1   11B -14.5
6/29/17 1:50 AM Reduced 1   11B -14.5
6/29/17 2:00 AM Reduced 1   11B -14.5
6/29/17 2:10 AM Reduced 1   11B -14.5
6/29/17 2:20 AM Reduced 1   11B -14.5
6/29/17 2:30 AM Reduced 1   11B -14.5
```

Code:

```
attach(wpplot)
wpplot$datefinish<-strptime(wpplot$Date, format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M %p")
```

**UPDATE**:

In using the strptime I am not able to discern between am/pm. The locale is set to English_United States (OS is Windows).

```
> Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME") 
[1] "English_United States.1252"
> 
> Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")
[1] "English_United States.1252" 
wpplot$datefinish<-strptime(wpplot$Date, format = "%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p")
> datefinish
[1] "2017-06-29 12:40:00 PDT" "2017-06-29 12:50:00 PDT" 
"2017-06-29 01:00:00 PDT" "2017-06-29 01:10:00 PDT"
```

Comment: provide output of `dput(head(wpplot,10))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The am/pm format only works when it is written in lower-case, not in AM/PM like in your example. Also note that I changed `%H` to `%I` as indicated in `?strptime`.

The below did the trick for me.

```
wpplot$Date       <- tolower(wpplot$Date)
wpplot$datefinish <- strptime(wpplot$Date, format = "%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p")
```

In the documentation, however, it also states that the AM/PM behaviour is locale-specific:

> Locale-specific conversions to and from character strings are used where appropriate and available. This affects the names of the days and months, the AM/PM indicator (if used) and the separators in formats such as %x and %X, via the setting of the LC_TIME locale category.

## Update

We can change the times a bit in order to be sure we understand the am/pm concept correctly (is 12:40 AM in the afternoon or just past midnight?).

```
wpplot$Date[1] <- "6/29/17 02:40 pm"  # This is definitely 14:40 29th of June

# CORRECT:
strptime(wpplot$Date, format = "%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p")
# [1] "2017-06-29 14:40:00 CEST" "2017-06-29 12:50:00 CEST"
# [3] "2017-06-29 01:00:00 CEST" "2017-06-29 01:10:00 CEST"
# [5] "2017-06-29 01:20:00 CEST"
```

Note that I used `format = "%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p"` and not `format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M %p"`:

```
# WRONG
strptime(wpplot$Date, format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M %p")
# [1] "2017-06-29 02:40:00 CEST" "2017-06-29 12:50:00 CEST"
# [3] "2017-06-29 01:00:00 CEST" "2017-06-29 01:10:00 CEST"
# [5] "2017-06-29 01:20:00 CEST"
```

Comment: Thank you for the heads-up regarding the case of am/pm. However, even after the conversion the newly datefinish column still does not contain the am/pm information.

Comment: @David I edited the question, based on your edits and another thought from my side. Apparently you had lowercase am/pm already, but it turns out that doesn't change anything to the result..

Comment: I also updated my question, adding the 'Sys.setlocale' info and the strptime results - still will not discern between am/pm.

Comment: Just to make sure, you are aware that `12:40 PM` is in the afternoon, right? From the 12 examples you provided, the 'wrong' and 'right'  transformation result in the same time, even if the code produces the real correct times.

Comment: Yes, after looking at the data it appears that it was being inputted incorrectly. I have fixed the values and all works well. Thank you for your help.